# column name as argument for printing particular column from dataframe

Tags: r

I'm having a dataframe as like below. I need to extract AveElapsed or Runtime from the dataframe based on the region

```
    >avg_data
    region  SN      value   AveElapsed      Runtime
    beta    1       32      1372            943.668
    alpha   2       44      1408            966.495
    beta    3       55      1384            951.091
    beta    4       60      1390            954.929
    atp     5       22      1442            924.381
```

I need to take "AveElapsed" column or "Runtime" column based on the argument.

Below command is working fine. But how I can

```
    >avg_data[avg_data$region =="beta", "AveElapsed"]
    [1] 1372 1408 1384 1390 1442
```

But when I use function

```
    newfun(z, h)
    {
            avg_data[avg_data$region == z, h]
    }
```

When I call this function

```
    newfun(beta, AveElapsed)
```

I'm getting error like this.. Please advise.

```
    Error in "[.data.frame"(avg_data, avg_data$region == z, h) :
             object "beta" not found
```

Also When I tried using as like below it is not working..

```
    M=AveElapsed
    avg_data[avg_data$region == "beta", M]
```

Comment: Quotes are needed. Otherwise R thinks you are referencing a named object. So, `newfun("beta", "AveElapsed")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because object `beta` doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
newfun("beta", "AveElapsed")
```

That passes a character object containing the string "beta" rather than the contents of a (non-existent) object called beta.  Same goes for "AveElapsed" as @BenBarnes points out.

Comment: Probably `"AveElapsed"`, too?

Comment: I'm trying to use like this way... It is not working... Please advise.. `M=AveElapsed
avg_data[avg_data$region == "beta", M]`

Comment: @Tamilan Please don't take this the wrong way, as it is meant to help not to be snarky: I suggest you spend some time with a basic R tutorial.  These are very basic mistakes that you would not be making if you took a little bit of time to understand data structures.  If you are going to do it that way, you should set `M <- "AveElapsed"` .